# inline javascript in html returned from ajax call not working

Tags: jquery

Somebody please suggest how to load javascript in remote html called from ajax call?

I'm facing problem in dispaying remote html having java script which is called from ajax load function. The joomla article display fine if contains only plain html and css where as it doesn't display properly the tab contents and image slider. The javascript call isn't working.

please give an example to display tab functionality or slider in remote html called by ajax. My code pasted isn't allowing to post question.

---

Here is the link. 
http://www.seetapappu.site40.net/test/testSplitmenu-tab.html
http://www.seetapappu.site40.net/test/remote-html.html
Please check in some editor.
the /templates/finger/js/activatables.js file is referred from following code.
activatables('page', ['page-1', 'page-2', 'page-3']);

I'm really struggling to refer the above javascript code. It works fine in standalone page. Please tell how to refer it from ajax. I really can't understand your div tag trick to make the ajax call whcih can fit with my existing code of ajax request. Could you look it and suggest me?

Comment: I've merged your unregistered accounts. You can now edit your question and leave comments under answers that you receive.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery won't let you load remote HTML with inline JavaScript.  This is actually a restriction of several browsers, so jQuery strips out any script tags via regex to avoid errors in those browsers (as well as to keep the API consistent across all supported browsers).

---

edit: this is where jQuery actually strips out the script tags - https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.3/src/ajax.js#L216

Comment: Thanks for the note. So, how to display tab/slider functionality in remote html without using javascript? The remote html is actually called by ajax load function. I there any way to handle this requirement. please suggest. thanks in advance.

Comment: You're going to need to separate the remote HTML from it's JavaScript.  For example, in the HTML you could include a data attribute on the top-level element, with a value pointing at the associated JavaScript. E.g., <div data-js='/static/js/foo.js'>...</div>.  Then in your success handler, you can do something like $.getScript($(respData).data('js')); Hard to provide a better code example w/out seeing yours.